# Autofill Destination using a named range and LastRow

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to autofill from an offset from a named range `Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(1, -1)` down until a previously declared LastRow

I can't work out what the syntax is for autofilling from a named cell down to the last row is.

I cannot work out how to do this without using Select. I could use select to do what I want by putting in a piece of code to select the cell I want, and then putting in the line:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Tidy_Emails_tester()
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("Home Email 1").Name = "Home_Email_1"
    Range("Home_Email_1").EntireColumn.Insert

    Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "Suggested Email"
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(1, -1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[2],RC[1],IF(RC[4],RC[3],IF(RC[6],RC[5],IF(RC[8],RC[7],IF(RC[1]<>"""",RC[1],IF(RC[3]<>"""",RC[3],IF(RC[5]<>"""",RC[5],IF(RC[7]<>"""",RC[7],IF(RC[9]<>"""",RC[9],"""")))))))))"

    Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(1, -1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(1, -1). & LastRow
End Sub
```

Grateful for any help you can provide making this work without select.

Cheers

Comment: Please review your code, because give me a syntax error when write it into VBA.

Comment: Hi Elbert. You are right that the code does not work, sorry If I didn't make that clear. The last line does not work but I left it in as an indication of what I am trying to do. You might need to delete that last line and write it from scratch. Cheers!

Comment: Your question is vague, any way i think i could give you an answer, BUT please re-edit your question, and be more clear about what you really want. and read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I figured out how to do it, I didn't realise you can write a relative range after a named range. The solution was this:

Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(1, -1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("Home_Email_1").Offset(1, -1).Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Also, I can see now that the code I pasted in to the question box looks a bit messed up - it's put multiple lines into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.FillDown` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) to fill the formula down.

```
 Range("Home_Email_1", Cells(LastRow, Range("Home_Email_1").Column)).FillDown
```

We use the [`.Cells` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) to build the `.Range` object, which we want to populate the formula down.